# Traverse through HTML tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to traverse through a table based on a id of nested inner HTML element. And then I have to apply style for all elements which has a child element with class "second".

Code:-

```
$('#edit-a-25946-second-procedure').parent().parent().parent().children().each(
    function(index){
        $(this + ' second').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Without showing us your HTML, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you're having duplicated id, you need to use class instead since `id` must be unique:

```
class="edit-a-25946-second-procedure"
```

then you can try to shorten your code using **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**:

```
$('.edit-a-25946-second-procedure').closest('table').find('.second').css('display', 'none');
```